# Updating a date back one day in Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, date

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXFXk.png)

I am trying to update a date in a SQL table, I’d like to update the column create_time back one day in sql
Then I want the final output should be:

```
CRETE_TIME
2021-12-14 16:52:31
2021-12-14 16:52:36
2021-12-03 16:52:40
```

All the create_time are back one day.
Any ideas? I am a bloody beginner

Comment: what is your question

Comment: I’d like to update the column create_time back one day in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
update table_name
set CREATE_TIME = CREATE_TIME - 1;
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I have tried it.

Comment: @glii001 care to elaborate? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Update table_name
set create_time =
create_time -1